# Making a single-line 'if' statement without an 'else' in Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, if-statement

Is there any way to do this in a single line, but without using a 'None'?:

```
folders = ['Project 1', 'Project 2']
files = os.listdir('/home/user/Documents/Python')
for i in files:
    files.remove(i) if i in folders else None
```

Could one 'skip' the 'else' statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should do `files = [_ for _ in files if _ not in folders]`, the Python style.

Comment: @zyxue: `_` is only for unused variables.

Comment: @zyxue don't use `_` unless it is a throwaway variable, which it is not.

Comment: In this case, it is a throwaway as it won't be needed out of the list comprehension, no?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`if i in files: files.remove(i)`

Comment: Note: but this isn't the recommended style. Better split into two lines.