# Single line if statement in lambda function without else statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

This question might be bit of odd, since I'm focusing on lambda functions I wanted to filter array and return a new array which will contains values that divisible by 2. To do so my code is...

```
alist = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]

devided = [(lambda x: x if x%2 == 0 : return x)(x) for x in alist]

print(devided)
```

I'm getting the result of this...

```
[None, 4, None, 16, None, 36, None, 64, None, 100]
```

I need to get rid of these `None` values. It might be a good way I could skip the executing of `else` statement.
I also tried [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44186672/5975253) doesn't seems to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: The `[(lambda x: x if x%2 == 0 : return x)(x) for x in alist]` is invalid syntax. I don't understand why you need lambda here, simple list comprehension will work: `[x for x in alist if not x % 2]`

Comment: Do you have to use lambda?  `devided = [x for x in alist if x % 2 == 0]` seems more straightforward.

Comment: Why, oh why, are you using an immediately executed lambda expression inside a list comprehension?

Comment: I'm learning lambda functions and need practice it, So that's why I used it (bit of naive approach, I know)

Comment: @GovindaMalavipathirana it simply doesn't make any sense. In any case, there is no mystery to lambda functions, they are just like regular functions, except anonymous. If you want to use a function, here, just use `filter`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lambdas will always return *something*. And with the way you have it (ignoring the invalid syntax) that *something* will always go into the list that results from your list comprehension. So for your purposes, you can just move the `if` from inside the lambda to the list comprehension itself. In fact, you don't really need a lambda at all.

```
devided = [x for x in alist if x%2==0]
```

But if you really want a lambda, it would look like this:

```
devided = [x for x in alist if (lambda x:x%2==0)(x)]
```

When you put an `if` at the end of the list comprehension, you're telling the interpreter that if the statement evaluates to `False`, (which in your case means that `x` is an odd number`), that there shouldn't be anything at all in the resulting list. Basically saying "Ignore this value, I don't want it mapped to anything, I don't want to see any evidence that it ever existed when I look at the resulting list".

Which is different from putting an `if` statement inside a lambda at the start of the list comprehension. When you do that, you're telling the interpreter that you want the value returned by that lambda to be in the resulting list, even if that value is `None`.

Comment: Thanks it worked out. But could you explain how this execution happens, bit of confusing..

Answer (score 2):

A python function will always return something. If you don't specify what to return, then it will return None. You can use the function filter for what you want:

```py
devided = filter(lambda x: x%2 == 0, alist)
```

**Edit**
To get a list use:

```py
*devided, = filter(lambda x: x%2 == 0, alist)
```

Thanks to @mypetlion for the correction

Comment: Should be noted that your solution will result in `devided` pointing to a `filter` object, and not a `list` like in OP's sample. You could do `*devided, = filter(...)` or `devided = list(filter(...))` to get the expected `list`.

Comment: Can you clarify why *devided, = ... gets a list?

Comment: The `*` tells the interpreter to "unpack" the variable on the right side of the `=`. (There is more to star expression syntax, but let's keep it simple for now). So if you have an iterable, or multiple values on the right side, they get turned into a `list`. Try this: `*a, = 'this is a test'`, or this: `*a, b, c = 'this is another test'`. It's easier to understand if you play around with it a bit. You can read about it here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/